# Is it better to cache JSON string or object tree?

Tags: c#, .net, json, caching

I'm looking for tips about general problem: if I'm doing web service calls that return JSON strings, and  I'd like to cache responses for several minutes because they may be reused several times, do I cache JSON string or deserialized object tree?

Say JSON string is 400-4000kb in memory, and object tree with subset of JSON string is 600-6000kb in memory. Will garbage collection be different for string and tree?

There are horror stories about large strings staying forever in LOH in .net 2.0 - are they still relevant for .net 4.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LOH issues (LOH Fragmentation) are not only related to strings, they are related to any object that has a size of 85000 bytes as that is the trigger point for an object to be placed on the LOH. They are still very relevant for .Net 4.0 and 4.5.

In answer to your question, I wouldn't think that the garbage collection pattern would be any different for either case, string or tree. However, you may have a performance benefit from storing it as a tree in search terms; since you have the JSON string coming off the wire, I would cache that and then create the tree on 1st use, at which point the tree is kept until next refresh.

For more info on the LOH, see [here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc534993.aspx)